# Why am I getting a TypeError when trying to run my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting `Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'this.props.customer' as it is undefined.` error.  My code seems to be correct from the looks of it but despite this fact, I'm still getting the aforementioned error.  Is there something minuscule that I'm overlooking?

Here's `CustomerList.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Customer from "./Customer";

class CustomerList extends Component {
    render() {
        const customers = this.props.customers;
        return(
            <div className="data">
                <table className="ui celled table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style={{ width: '50px', textAlign: 'center' }}>#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>E-mail</th>
                            <th style={{ width: '148px' }}>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    {
                        customers.map(customer => {
                            return <Customer customer={customer} key={customer.id} />;
                        })
                    }
                        <Customer/>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CustomerList;
```

Here's `Customer.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Customer extends Component {
    render() {
        const { id, first_name, last_name, email } = this.props.customer;
        return (
            <tr>
                <td style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{id}</td>
                <td>{`${first_name} ${last_name}`}</td>
                <td>{email}</td>
                <td>
                    <button className="mini ui blue button">Edit</button>
                    <button className="mini ui red button">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

export default Customer;
```

Comment: the reason is that `this.props.customer` is undefined - and the code you've posted doesn't indicate it exists at all

Comment: Can you add `console.log(this.props.customer)` to `Customer` render? If Customer component(s) renders more than once, do you log `undefined` anytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the `map` part you have a single

```
<Customer/>
```

This call to the `Customer` component has no parameters, so `customer` is undefined. That is why you get the error.

Comment: Wow... thanks man.  I was stuck on this for 2 days :(.  I greatly appreciate it.